# javascript array methods? functions?

Tags: javascript

In my code I have a simple :

```
var myArray = [];
```

When I look at this in Firebug script debugging, I see a bunch of methods or functions :

```
myArray  []

add function()
clear function()
clone function()
contains function()
copy function()
count function()
. . .
```

But what exactly ARE these? They are not defined anywhere that I can find and they don't match up at all with w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp

So where did they come from?

Comment: MB another loaded script has polluted `Array.prototype` with those methods.

Comment: Yury is probably right, but it could even be those methods were hung on Object or Object.prototype